# Controlling the LED flash light on Windows Phone Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Anyone know how apps like Flashlight 7 keep the flash illuminated for an extended period of time? I've found ways in code to make it light up intermittently but not continuously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It loads the Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended assembly through reflection, then use Microsoft.Phone.VideoCamera class to control the flash.

Comment: Looks like when I will use this solution, I will have problems with the review before publishing to `Windows Sotore`. Correct me if I'm wrong.